# copying file of remote source to remote target folder

Tags: ssh, scp

I need to copy a file from a remote server to the same remote server, but with limited bandwidth. I have decided to do so with scp.

```
scp -l 8000 myuser@myserver:/my/source/path/myfile.data myuser@myserver:/my/target/path/
```

So now my question is: Will the stream of the file travel from the remote server to my local machine and then back to the remote server?

Comment: Why don't you use a `ssh myuser@myserver cp /my/source/path/myfile.data /my/target/path/`?

Comment: @JGK you can't limit the bandwidth with cp

Comment: Sorry I missed that :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the `scp` [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/scp.1.html):

```
 -3      Copies between two remote hosts are transferred through the
         local host.  Without this option the data is copied directly
         between the two remote hosts.  Note that this option disables
         the progress meter.
```

So no, the data will not be transferred through your local machine unless you specify the `-3` flag. See [this superuser post](https://superuser.com/questions/686394/scp-between-two-remote-hosts-from-my-third-pc) on why you may or may not want to do this.